# Popup appears consecutively when it should get displayed just once

Tags: java, swing

First, apology for the title for the problem. I wasn't sure what to write. Hence a detailed explanation about the problem is given below:-

So the below code snippet runs absolute fine with just one hitch. This code actually fetches relevant results from database based on search functionality and displays in the JTable. Out of 5 columns in Jtable, 4 columns retrieve their values from database and the 5th column contains Jbuttons. Now when the user clicks the Jbutton then based on the value for the **SECTION NAME** for that particular row, a popup gets fetched . All of this runs fine. The hitch is that the popup should ideally get displayed only once. But according to my program, the number of consecutive times the popup appears depends on the number of times the user searched for a query. Say for eg after searching 3 terms the user searches for his 4th search query and presses the button and the condition also satisfies for popup to generate then this popup gets displayed consecutively 4 times. How to fix this ?

```
public class r_search_2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

     static int counter;
    static String sname="";
      DefaultTableModel model;
    //String section_name = "";

    JFrame frame1;
    JLabel l0, l1, l2;
    JComboBox c1;
    JButton b1;
    Connection con;
    ResultSet rs, rs1;
    Statement st, st1;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    String ids;
    JTable table  = new JTable(new JTableModel());
    //static JTable table  = new JTable();
    String[] columnNames = {"SECTION NAME", "REPORT NAME", "CONTACT", "LINK","METRICS"};
    String from;
    Vector v = new Vector();
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();


    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.LEADING, 60,25));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    r_search_2() 
    {

        l1 = new JLabel("Search");
        b1 = new JButton("submit");

        //l0.setBounds(100, 50, 350, 40);
        l1.setBounds(75, 110, 75, 20);
        b1.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 20);

        b1.addActionListener(this);

        topPanel.add(l1,BorderLayout.LINE_START);


        try 
        {

            File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
                String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ= " + path);
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select index_name from Index1");
           while (rs.next())
           {
                ids = rs.getString(1);
                v.add(ids);

            }
            c1 = new JComboBox(v);
            c1.setEditable(true);c1.setSelectedItem("");
            c1.setBounds(150, 110, 150, 20);


            topPanel.add(c1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            topPanel.add(b1,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            st.close();
            rs.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
       // setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == b1)
        {
            showTableData();
        }
     }

    public void showTableData()
    {
        // int counter=0;

         table.setRowHeight(35);

         JTableHeader th = table.getTableHeader();
         th.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
         th.setFont(th.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
         th.setForeground( Color.BLACK); 
         th.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

       // DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
         model=new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

        table.setModel(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        from = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();
        if(from.equals(""))
        {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a search term", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {

        TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
        table.getColumn("METRICS").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);

        table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(table));
        //static int i=0;
         String section_name = "";
         String report_name = "";
         String contact_name = "";
         String link = "";
        try
        {

        pst = con.prepareStatement("select distinct Section.Section_Name,Report.Report_Name,Report.Link,Contact.Contact_Name "
                                        + "FROM (( Section INNER JOIN Report ON Report.Section_ID=Section.Section_ID ) INNER JOIN Contact ON Contact.Contact_ID=Report.Contact_ID )  LEFT JOIN Metrics ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID  "
                                                                + " WHERE Section.Section_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Report.Report_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Metrics.Metric_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' OR Contact.Contact_Name LIKE '%"+from+"%' ");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            int i = 0; 
            while (rs.next()) {
                section_name = rs.getString("Section_Name");
                report_name = rs.getString("Report_Name");
                contact_name = rs.getString("Contact_Name");
                link = rs.getString("Link");
              //  data_values(section_name,report_name,contact_name,link);


                model.addRow(new Object[]{section_name, report_name, contact_name, link});
                System.out.println("section name at row"+section_name);
               /* s_name(String section_name)
                {

                }*/
                sname=section_name;
              //  getsecname(section_name);
                i++;

            }


            if (i < 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        }
        mainPanel.add(scroll);

        mainPanel.revalidate();
        mainPanel.repaint();

    }

    private static class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
    {       


        @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            //JButton button = (JButton)value;
            JButton button = new JButton("LIST OF METRICS");
            button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            if (isSelected) {
                button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } 
            else
            {
                button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
                button.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            }
            return button;  
        }
    }


    private static class JTableButtonMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        private final JTable table;

        public JTableButtonMouseListener(JTable table)
        {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            counter=0;
            System.out.println("***************************************************************");
            System.out.println("counter value="+counter++);
            System.out.println("/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
            int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int row    = e.getY()/table.getRowHeight(); 

            if (row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0 && column < table.getColumnCount() && column >= 0) {
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                System.out.println("row clicked="+row);
                System.out.println("column clicked="+column);
                System.out.println("object value="+value);
              /* public void getsecname(String s)
                {
                    String ss=s;
                }*/

                if(value==null)
                {
                    Object v=table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("object value="+v);
                     String s = v.toString();
                     if(s.equals("Executive Summary"))
                     {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "list of metrics", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                     }
                }
                if (value instanceof JButton) {
                    ((JButton)value).doClick();
                }
            }
        }
    }
     public  class JTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    //private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[] {"Id", "Stuff", "METRICS"};
                      String[] columnNames = {"SECTION NAME", "REPORT NAME", "CONTACT", "LINK","METRICS"};
                    private  final Class<?>[] COLUMN_TYPES = new Class<?>[] {String.class, String.class,String.class, String.class,  JButton.class};

                    @Override public int getColumnCount()
                    {
                                  //  System.out.println("inside getcolumncount");
                                   // System.out.println(columnNames.length);
                                    return columnNames.length;

                    }

                    @Override public int getRowCount()
                    {
                                   // System.out.println("inside getrowcount");
                                    return 100;
                    }

                    @Override public String getColumnName(int columnIndex)
                    {
                                   // System.out.println("inside getColumnName");
                                    //System.out.println("column index="+columnIndex);
                                    //System.out.println(columnNames[columnIndex]);
                                   // System.out.println("section name="+section_name);
                                    return columnNames[columnIndex];
        }

                    @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
                    {
                                  //  System.out.println("inside columnIndex");
                                    //System.out.println(COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex]);

                                    return COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex];
                    }

                    @Override public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex)
                    {
                                    System.out.println("inside getValueAt");
                                    switch (columnIndex) {
                                                    case 0: return rowIndex;
                                                    case 1: //return "Text for "+rowIndex;
                                                    case 2: // fall through
                                                    case 3: final JButton button = new JButton(columnNames[columnIndex]);
                                    //            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                                                    button.setSize(new Dimension(10,10));
                                                    //System.out.println("halloween");
                                                                                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                                                                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                                                                                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(button), 
                                                                                                                                                    "Button clicked for row "+rowIndex);
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                    });
                                                                                    return button;
                                                    default: return "";
                                    }
                    }              
    }

   /* public String getRowData(int row) {
        if (model != null) {
           return section_name;
            // return row of data from model here 
        } 
        else
        {
           // throw some exception
        }
        return contact_name;
     }*/

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        /*try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {

                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        } */       

                r_search_2 s=new r_search_2();
                //new r_search_2();
                JFrame fr=new JFrame("Search Executive Reports");
                //fr.add(s.getUI());
                fr.add(s.mainPanel);
                fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                fr.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                fr.setSize(1000, 400);
                //fr.pack();
                fr.setVisible(true);



      //  new r_search_2();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arijit: Please have a look at my code.This is what I was referring to Can u find a fix ?

Comment: have written name of button that creates an issue as "submit"?

Comment: @coreJavare :this button "submit" is for submitting the text that the user wants to search. this is different than the button that is used in the jtable

Comment: then what is the lable of button ?

Comment: sorry but couldn't get you ! kindly elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last figured out your problem. You have to remove the mouse listner. put the below code at the begining of your showTableData() method

```
MouseListener[] M = table.getMouseListeners();
        if(M.length>0)
            for(int i=0;i<M.length;i++)
        table.removeMouseListener(M[i]);
```

complete code after modification:

```
public class r_search_2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static int counter;
    static String sname = "";
    DefaultTableModel model;
    // String section_name = "";

    JFrame frame1;
    JLabel l0, l1, l2;
    JComboBox c1;
    JButton b1;
    Connection con;
    ResultSet rs, rs1;
    Statement st, st1;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    String ids;
    JTable table = new JTable(new JTableModel());
    // static JTable table = new JTable();
    String[] columnNames = { "SECTION NAME", "REPORT NAME", "CONTACT", "LINK",
            "METRICS" };
    String from;
    Vector v = new Vector();
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.LEADING, 60, 25));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    r_search_2() {

        l1 = new JLabel("Search");
        b1 = new JButton("submit");

        // l0.setBounds(100, 50, 350, 40);
        l1.setBounds(75, 110, 75, 20);
        b1.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 20);

        b1.addActionListener(this);

        topPanel.add(l1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        try {

//          File dbFile = new File("executive_db.accdb");
//          String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
//          con = DriverManager
//                  .getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ= "
//                          + path);
//          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
//          st = con.createStatement();
//          rs = st.executeQuery("select index_name from Index1");
//          while (rs.next()) {
//              ids = rs.getString(1);
//              v.add(ids);
//
//          }
            v.add("aa");
            v.add("bb");
            c1 = new JComboBox(v);
            c1.setEditable(true);
            c1.setSelectedItem("");
            c1.setBounds(150, 110, 150, 20);

            topPanel.add(c1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            topPanel.add(b1, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            st.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        // setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
            showTableData();
        }
    }

    public void showTableData() {
        // int counter=0;
        model = new DefaultTableModel();

        MouseListener[] M = table.getMouseListeners();
        if(M.length>0)
            for(int i=0;i<M.length;i++)
        table.removeMouseListener(M[i]);

        table.setRowHeight(35);

        JTableHeader th = table.getTableHeader();
        th.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        th.setFont(th.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        th.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        th.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        // DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

        table.setModel(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        scroll
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll
                .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        from = (String) c1.getSelectedItem();
        if (from.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a search term",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {

            TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
            table.getColumn("METRICS").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);

            table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(table));
            // static int i=0;
            String section_name = "";
            String report_name = "";
            String contact_name = "";
            String link = "";
            try {

//              pst = con
//                      .prepareStatement("select distinct Section.Section_Name,Report.Report_Name,Report.Link,Contact.Contact_Name "
//                              + "FROM (( Section INNER JOIN Report ON Report.Section_ID=Section.Section_ID ) INNER JOIN Contact ON Contact.Contact_ID=Report.Contact_ID )  LEFT JOIN Metrics ON Metrics.Report_ID=Report.Report_ID  "
//                              + " WHERE Section.Section_Name LIKE '%"
//                              + from
//                              + "%' OR Report.Report_Name LIKE '%"
//                              + from
//                              + "%' OR Metrics.Metric_Name LIKE '%"
//                              + from
//                              + "%' OR Contact.Contact_Name LIKE '%"
//                              + from
//                              + "%' ");
//              ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                int i = 0;
                //while (rs.next()) {
                    section_name = "Section_Name";
                    report_name = "Report_Name";
                    contact_name = "Contact_Name";
                    link = "Link";
                    // data_values(section_name,report_name,contact_name,link);

                    model.addRow(new Object[] { section_name, report_name,
                            contact_name, link });
                    System.out.println("section name at row" + section_name);
                    /*
                     * s_name(String section_name) {
                     * 
                     * }
                     */
                    sname = section_name;
                    // getsecname(section_name);
                    i++;

            //  }

                if (i < 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found",
                            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        mainPanel.add(scroll);

        mainPanel.revalidate();
        mainPanel.repaint();

    }

    private static class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            // JButton button = (JButton)value;
            JButton button = new JButton("LIST OF METRICS");
            button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            if (isSelected) {
                button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
                button.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            }
            return button;
        }
    }

    private static class JTableButtonMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private final JTable table;

        public JTableButtonMouseListener(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            counter = 0;
            System.out
                    .println("***************************************************************");
            System.out.println("counter value=" + counter++);
            System.out
                    .println("/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
            int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int row = e.getY() / table.getRowHeight();

            if (row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0
                    && column < table.getColumnCount() && column >= 0) {
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
                System.out.println("row clicked=" + row);
                System.out.println("column clicked=" + column);
                System.out.println("object value=" + value);
                /*
                 * public void getsecname(String s) { String ss=s; }
                 */

                if (value == null) {
                    Object v = table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                    System.out
                            .println("--------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("object value=" + v);
                    String s = v.toString();
                    if (s.equals("Section_Name")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "list of metrics",
                                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                if (value instanceof JButton) {
                    ((JButton) value).doClick();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class JTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        // private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[] {"Id",
        // "Stuff", "METRICS"};
        String[] columnNames = { "SECTION NAME", "REPORT NAME", "CONTACT",
                "LINK", "METRICS" };
        private final Class<?>[] COLUMN_TYPES = new Class<?>[] { String.class,
                String.class, String.class, String.class, JButton.class };

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            // System.out.println("inside getcolumncount");
            // System.out.println(columnNames.length);
            return columnNames.length;

        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            // System.out.println("inside getrowcount");
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            // System.out.println("inside getColumnName");
            // System.out.println("column index="+columnIndex);
            // System.out.println(columnNames[columnIndex]);
            // System.out.println("section name="+section_name);
            return columnNames[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            // System.out.println("inside columnIndex");
            // System.out.println(COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex]);

            return COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
            System.out.println("inside getValueAt");
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return rowIndex;
            case 1: // return "Text for "+rowIndex;
            case 2: // fall through
            case 3:
                final JButton button = new JButton(columnNames[columnIndex]);
                // button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                button.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
                // System.out.println("halloween");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane
                                .getFrameForComponent(button),
                                "Button clicked for row " + rowIndex);
                    }
                });
                return button;
            default:
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * public String getRowData(int row) { if (model != null) { return
     * section_name; // return row of data from model here } else { // throw
     * some exception } return contact_name; }
     */

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /*
         * try { for (LookAndFeelInfo info :
         * UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
         * 
         * if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
         * UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName()); break;
         * 
         * } } } catch (Exception e) { // If Nimbus is not available, you can
         * set the GUI to another look and feel. }
         */

        r_search_2 s = new r_search_2();
        // new r_search_2();
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Search Executive Reports");
        // fr.add(s.getUI());
        fr.add(s.mainPanel);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        fr.setSize(1000, 400);
        // fr.pack();
        fr.setVisible(true);

        // new r_search_2();
    }
}
```

Comment: So are yo saying to remove the line table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(table)); from my code and adding your lines @ beginning of showTableData() ? It's not working if I do it this way ! :-(

Comment: run the full code. I have edited the answer. its working for me.

Comment: I am not asking you to remove any thing from your code. Just add my lines @ beginning of showTableData()

Comment: ! Oh great !! Thank you so much !! That did work. It would be kind if you could please explain the codes that you told to append ! Thanks a ton ! :-)

Comment: MouseListener[] M = table.getMouseListeners(); //this line is getting all mouselistners in to an array
        if(M.length>0) // check if the array has any element or not. That means for the first time execution this part will not work
            for(int i=0;i<M.length;i++)
        table.removeMouseListener(M[i]);// removing all mouse listners from the table

Answer (score 1):

You are adding new Listener every time you click search button , that creates no of new dialog box for every click.

```
table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(table));
```

Comment: Okay ! I get it. So how to fix that

Comment: add mouselistener in the constructor of r_search_2 only